# Fedora 15 - Limited RAM Access

Tags: linux, kernel, fedora, memory, i386

I have an issue with Fedora 15's available memory. The laptop it is installed on has 4GB of SDRAM, but Fedora only sees 2GB.

```
[njozwiak@calvin xpmc6720]$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2193       1994        198          0         59       1405
-/+ buffers/cache:        529       1663
Swap:         4255          0       4255
```

I realize F15 is a 32-bit OS, but I should still be able to access more than 2193MB. Any ideas?

```
[njozwiak@calvin xpmc6720]$ uname -a
Linux calvin 2.6.38.6-27.fc15.i686 #1 SMP Sun May 15 17:57:13 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kernel are you using? The kernel needs to have BIGMEM support.

Fedora 15 offers BIGMEM support in PAE kernels. So install (for example)
[the Fedora 15 2.6.38 PAE kernel](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/15805270/dir/fedora_15/com/kernel-PAE-2.6.38.6-27.fc15.i686.rpm.html).

Comment: `[njozwiak@calvin xpmc6720]$ uname -a
Linux calvin 2.6.38.6-27.fc15.i686 #1 SMP Sun May 15 17:57:13 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux.` How do I determine if my kernel supports bigmem?

Comment: @njozwiak: check your kernel config for options containing the string CONFIG_HIGHMEM. Some of these options need to be set to yes. Paste if you are not sure. Googling suggests that Fedora has bigmem support in PAE kernels. Search for a linux kernel with PAE in the string.